# cx_Oracle in Ubuntu: distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7

i try to install python dependencies for django project sdu.edu.kz. This project uses cx-Oracle. 
When i try:

```
./install_python_dependencies.sh install
```

It successfully installs all modules except one. The module of cx-Oracle. However, I installed the cx-Oracle program on my computer.

It prints the error:

```
Collecting cx-oracle==5.2 (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 82))
  Using cached cx_Oracle-5.2.tar.gz
   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/tmp/pip-build-RP7c9i/cx-oracle/setup.py", line 170, in <module>
       raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
   distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

   ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip build-RP7c9i/cx-oracle/
```

How to locate an Oracle software installation? Any ideas? Please, help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Oracle 12.x , cx_Oracle not available yet. So we need to download instant client with 11.x version.

Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html and accept License Agreement.

## Then download zip files with names as below

- instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
- instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip

## And unzip them with unzip command

```
unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip
```

Both will be extracted into a common directory named as "instantclient_11_2". Then add this to PATH with below commands.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/path-to_this/instantclient_11_2
cd $ORACLE_HOME
ln -s libclntsh.so.11.1   libclntsh.so
```

Open /etc/profile or .bashrc and following entries.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/location/of/your/files/instantclient_11_2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
```

then do `source ~/.bashrc` or `source /etc/profile`

And install these packages

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential unzip python-dev libaio-dev
```

after that use `pip` or `pip3` according to your Python version and then install it

```
pip3 install cx_Oracle
```

and try loading `cx_Oracle` module in Python interpreter.

Hope this helps.

Credit goes here: https://gist.github.com/kimus/10012910

Note: I have tried this on my Ubuntu 16.04 installation , it should work for you.

Comment: Raja, thank you. The file .bashrc was the solution of a problem

Comment: No Problem brother. Glad its helped you. I struggled same as you on installing but its came easy when I gone through right blog